# The best way to listen to external url JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, file-get-contents

I have a general and important question, I need to know what is the best way to listen to external url (not in my server) JSON.
I have an external supplier (I can't ask them to send me a private request), usually the url is blank page, once there is new "alert", a new JSON appear in this page, then, I need (as soon as possible) to do some actions (parse it, etc..).

Today, I'm working with PHP, Im sending every 1 second interval a request to get the page content, and checking, Im sure this is not smart enough.
I just tried FireBase (But I saw that I must be connected to their site), Angular.js? Node.js? (I have my own Server).

I would appreaciate hearing your thoughts on this!

Thank you!

Eran.

Comment: 1 request per second, it's too obvious, you may be blocked. You should store the json on your server, check each 5 mins if it changed and then update it on your server.

Comment: If they're not willing to ping you, then polling is your only option. But yes, as @PierreEmmanuelLallemant suggests, maybe 1 second interval is too short.

Comment: It sounds like what you are looking for is a IO socket. Not a getJSON request.

Comment: Do you have permission? If you do there is no problem with 1 second interval. HTTP request are meant to close the connection after sending it's data

Comment: Thank you all! @magreenberg Ill try Socket.io, 1 second interval is Ok, This server is ok for short polling.